# ABC is an acute-angled triangle whose altitude from the vertices meet the circumcircle

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles, circles

Let ABC be an acute-angled triangle. Let the altitudes from the vertices A, B, C meet the circumcircle at P, Q, R whose corresponding complex numbers are $z_1,z_2$ and $z_3$ respectively. If  is $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}$ is imaginary number then find the value of angle A.

My approach is illustrated below but not able to approach

[image]

Comment: Where have you found the problem? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I have added the picture where it is given position of $z_1,z_2,z_3$ we need to find $\frac{z_b-z_a}{z_c-z_a}$ but not able to find the angle.$P=z_1,Q=z_2,R=z_3$

Comment: $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}$ being imaginary implies that the points $z_2$ and $z_3$ are diametrically opposite. Drawing the figure like that and some constructions will give $A$ as 45 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A',B',C'$ be the intersection points of the altitudes with the circumscribed circle. Then we have:
$$
\angle BAC=\frac{\pi-\angle B'A'C'}2.
$$
From $$\Re\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}=0$$
we know $$\angle B'A'C'=\frac\pi2.$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From the given, we have $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1} = e^{i\frac\pi2}$, or $Arg \left( \frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\right) =\frac\pi2$

\begin{align}
\angle BAC & = \angle BAP + \angle CAP \\
& =  \angle BQP  + \angle CRP \\
 & =  Arg \left( \frac{z_2-z_1}{z_2-b} \right)  
 + Arg \left( \frac{z_3-c}{z_3-z_1} \right) \\
 & =  Arg \left( \frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1} \frac{z_3-c}{z_2-b} \right)  \\
& =  Arg \left( \frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1}\right) +Arg\left( \frac{z_3-c}{z_2-b} \right)  \\
& =  -\frac\pi2 +\angle RXQ  \\
& = - \frac\pi2 +(\pi - \angle BAC)  \\
\end{align}

which yields $\angle BAC = \frac\pi4$.